# Create var of type []string in Go

Tags: csv, go

Starting by saying I am fairly new to Go language.

My program takes a CSV and reads in each row as a []string and adds all of them to a slice. Another part of the program is supposed to add another entry to the slice containing new information, but I can't figure out how to declare a new entry as type []string. If it try to use a struct, the code, the []Customer type is incompatible with the []string type. If i convert the []string slice to type []Customer at the beginning, I lose function of being able to use time.Parse on certain parts of each entry. I cannot get the new entry to declare as type []string. Is there any way to do this? Code for reading the CSV and adding to a slice of type []string.

```
var customerInfo [][]string

for {
    record, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    customerInfo = append(customerInfo, record)
}
```

Code for time.Parse functionality and updating one column of the []string.

```
today := time.Now()
for i, e := range customerInfo {
    if i > 0 {
        lastOilChange, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", e[4])
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        diff := today.Sub(lastOilChange)
        diffInMonths := float64(diff.Hours() / 24 / 30)
        if diffInMonths > 6 {
            e[6] = today.Format("2006-01-02")
        }
    }
}
```

Code for adding a new row to the CSV (Currently the only part not working)

```
var newCust []string = {"1500", "Your Name", "Make Model", "City", "date1", "date2", "date3", "date4"}
customerInfo = append(customerInfo, newCust)
```

The error that I am getting when I run this program with the code for adding a new row to the CSV is

```
syntax error: unexpected {, expected expression
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals) is missing the [type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#LiteralType).  Add the type like this:

```
var newCust []string = []string{"1500", "Your Name", "Make Model", "City", "date1", "date2", "date3", "date4"}
```

Note the second `[]string`.

There's no need to repeat the type.  Use this code:

```
var newCust = []string{"1500", "Your Name", "Make Model", "City", "date1", "date2", "date3", "date4"}
```

or even [shorter](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

```
newCust := []string{"1500", "Your Name", "Make Model", "City", "date1", "date2", "date3", "date4"}
```